# Drag on a line segment control - calculate point on line

Tags: swift, math, vector

I have a line segment defined by P1 und P2 and a knob on that line which can be dragged. The drag should also work if the drag location L is away from the line segment.

One idea was to find the perpendicular line and then find the intersection. But that won`t work if the drag location L is extacly on the line segment or on the (infinite) line going through P1 and P2.

Infact at the end of the day this should be a simple slider-control with the only difference that the control is not always a horizontal or vertical line segment (where you can drag on) but can be of any angle.

Comment: What happens if “the drag location L is away from the line segment”? Does the knob stay on the line segment, but move as close as possible to the drag location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define V as the vector P2 - P1.  So there is a line defined by P1 + t V (for all real t), and your line segment (call it S) is the subset of that line where 0 ≤ t ≤ 1.

You want to find the point in S that is closest to your drag point L. For any t, the distance from L to the t point on the line is

```
sqrt((P1x + t Vx - Lx)^2 + (P1y + t Vy - Ly)^2)).
```

To find the closest point to L, we want to find the t that minimizes this distance. In fact it suffices to minimize the square of the distance

```
(P1x + t Vx - Lx)^2 + (P1y + t Vy - Ly)^2
```

which is sometimes called the *quadrance*. To find the t that minimizes the quadrance, we take the derivative of the quadrance with respect to t, set it equal to zero, and solve for t:

```
Solve[D[(P1x + t Vx - Lx)^2 + (P1y + t Vy - Ly)^2, t] == 0, t]
```

If you type that into [Mathematica](https://programming.wolframcloud.com/app/), you'll get the answer

```
{{t->(Lx Vx - P1x Vx + Ly Vy - P1y Vy) / (Vx^2 + Vy^2)}}
```

But that t could be any real number. You'll need to clamp it to the range 0 ... 1 to guarantee that you get a point in your line segment.

In Swift:

```
extension CGPoint {

    func closestPointOnLineSegment(start p1: CGPoint, end p2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let v = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
        var t: CGFloat = (self.x * v.x - p1.x * v.x + self.y * v.y - p1.y * v.y) / (v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y)
        if t < 0 { t = 0 }
        else if t > 1 { t = 1 }
        return CGPointMake(p1.x + t * v.x, p1.y + t * v.y)
    }

}
```

Example use:

```
let knobPoint = dragPoint.closestPointOnLineSegment(start: p1, end: p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find projection of point L onto line P1P2.
If denote vector **P**=P1P2, and vector **M** = P1L, then needed projection

**L'** = **P** * DotProduct(**M**, **P**) /  DotProduct(**P**, **P**)

Probably you really need to find a ratio of P1L' and P1P2, then

t  = DotProduct(**M**, **P**) /  DotProduct(**P**, **P**)